# When is a Lindelöf topological space separable?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

Let *X* be a topological space (neither metrizable nor second countable ).

1. If *X* is Lindelöf, when *X* is separable?
2. If *X* is separable, when *X* is Lindelöf?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are saying or asking.

Comment: fwiw: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Separable_Metacompact_Space_is_Lindel%C3%B6f

Answer (score 0):

1. See my answer to the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452055/is-there-any-condition-for-which-a-lindeloff-space-is-a-separable-space).
2. I'll try to look for an answer when I'll have time.